# How to find unknown variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given that $f(x)=  8x+m$ and $g(x)= x^2 - 3x +n$   and $g\circ f(x) =64x^2-8x$ where $m $ and $n$ are constants. Find the values of $m$ and $n$.

Can someone **point me in the correct direction** on how to solve this. Thank you

Comment: Just compute $g(f(x))$ and compare the result.

Comment: I didn't quite understand, sorry english is not my native language.

Comment: m=1,n =2 are the solutions

Answer (score 1):

Just write $$g\circ f(x) = g(f(x))= (8x+m)^2 -3(8x+m)+n $$
And then compare this with the $g\circ f$ given in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to see the process. We have

$$g\circ f: x \mapsto 8x + m =: y \mapsto y^{2} - 3y + n.$$

Since $y^{2} - 3y + n = (8x + m)^{2} - 3(8x + m) + n = 64x^{2} - 8x,$ you know the rest.

Comment: what is the rest

Comment: @user3184807: The OP does not ask for a complete answer. If you really like to know, consult Arpan above.

Comment: @user3184807: Your comment did not answer your question?

Comment: ik but it was a comment, you answered the question

Comment: @user3184807: Why do not you bother the other answerer? Find somebody else to find fault without justification.

Comment: To the downvoter: Avoid arbitrarily downvoting just because you cannot understand. Every downvote for something should be accompanied a reason. Take a look at the OP's question. The OP asks for a DIRECTION.